# Python function: Please help me in this one

Tags: python, python-3.x

okay these two functions are related to each other and fortunately the first one is solved but the other is a big mess and it should give me 17.5 but it only gives me 3 so why doesn't it work out??

```
def split_on_separators(original, separators):
    """ (str, str) -> list of str

    Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from the original string
    determined by splitting the string on any of the separators.
    separators is a string of single-character separators.

    >>> split_on_separators("Hooray! Finally, we're done.", "!,")
    ['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
    """
    result = []
    newstring = ''

    for index,char in enumerate(original):
        if char in separators or index==len(original) -1:
            result.append(newstring)
            newstring=''
            if '' in result:
                result.remove('')
        else:
            newstring+=char
    return result

def average_sentence_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text contains at least one sentence. A sentence is defined
    as a non-empty string of non-terminating punctuation surrounded by 
    terminating punctuation or beginning or end of file. Terminating 
    punctuation is defined as !?.

    Return the average number of words per sentence in text.   

    >>> text = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
         'To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
         'Of cabbages; and kings.\n'
         'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n'
         'and whether pigs have wings.\n']
    >>> average_sentence_length(text)
    17.5
    """
    words=0
    Sentences=0
    for line in text:
        words+=1
    sentence=split_on_separators(text,'?!.')
    for sep in sentence:
        Sentences+=1

    ASL=words/Sentences
    return ASL
```

Comment: `for line in text: words += 1`? This doesn't count the number of words.

Comment: Also, `split_on_separators` accepts a string, and `text` is a list.

Comment: yeah I know that for line in text: words+=1 won't count the number of words...that's the problem..How can I make it count the number of words??

Answer (score 0):

words can be counted by spliting each sentence in the list using space and counting the length of that list. would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the need for your first function by using regular expressions to split on separators. The regular expression function is [**re.split()**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split). Here is a cleaned up version that gets the right result:

```
import re

def average_sentence_length(text):

    # Join all the text into one string and remove all newline characters
    # Joining all text into one string allows us to find the sentences much
    # easier, since multiple list items in 'text' could be one whole sentence
    text = "".join(text).replace('\n', '')

    # Use regex to split the sentences at delimiter characters !?.
    # Filter out any empty strings that result from this function,
    # otherwise they will count as words later on
    sentences = filter(None, re.split('[!?.]', text))

    # Set the word sum variable
    wordsum = 0.0

    for s in sentences:
            # Split each sentence (s) into its separate words and add them
            # to the wordsum variable
            words = s.split(' ')
            wordsum += len(words)

    return wordsum / len(sentences)


data = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
     ' To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
     'Of cabbages; and kings.\n'
     'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n'
     'and whether pigs have wings.\n']

print average_sentence_length(data)
```

The one issue with this function is that with the text you provided, it returns 17.0 instead of 17.5. This is because there is no space in between *"...the Walrus said"* and *"To talk of..."*. There is nothing that can be done there besides adding the space that should be there in the first place.

If the first function (`split_on_separators`) is required for the project, than you can replace the `re.split()` function with your function. Using regular expressions is a bit more reliable and a lot more lightweight than writing an entire function for it, however.

**EDIT**

I forgot to explain the `filter()` function. Basically if you give the first argument of type `None`, it takes the second argument and removes all "false" items in it. Since an empty string is considered false in Python, it is removed. You can read more about `filter()` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)